# required php dom generator

Tags: php

Hello I have some functions that generate HTML code snippets like

```
echo "<div class='thtphoto' id='xcyz''>"
for($i = 0; $i <count($aFotos); $i++) {

echo "<div  onclick=\"selectPhoto('".aFotos[i]['url']. "'\")" class='miniphoto_on' id='div$i'">
....
...
..

}
```

if someone knows any class that I can use to create such HTML snippets using that class will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you look at Smarty or Mustache ? Because you will neither be happy with this current solution nor with a DOM representation. At least for the presented use case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: @Gordon - Before one negative votes atleast one should read the Question. Unbelievable.

Comment: @user Before one asks a superfluous question, one should use the Search function. Unbelievable!

Comment: @Gordon -You even now did not try to read the question! I am not looking for any PARSER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user if you had taken five minutes to at least look at the suggested solutions in that answer, you would have noticed that they allow parsing *and* generating HTML. The only exception to that is XMLReader. But guess what? There is XMLWriter, which you could have easily found by at least looking at the PHP Manual before asking. Or how about going through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+html+php or do a Google. Because all that would have given you ample results. The -1 is for not doing research.

Comment: I don't understand what needs generating here in the first place. What's wrong with the method you currently use?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: Represents an entire HTML or XML document; serves as the root of the document tree.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Will your snippets always be formatted exactly the same?

Comment: I depends on data that I will receive from WebService.